# Query: I need to retrieve only those rows where value for particular “Pro” column is only A

Tags: sql

Table:

```
ID      Pro     Value      Date
1234    1111    A          sysdate
1234    1111    B          sysdate
1234    1111    C          sysdate
And many more …..
```

Query: I need to retrieve only those rows where value for particular “Pro” column is only A.

Note: If I use query like `select * from table where pro=’1111’ and value=’A’;` -- then it will fetch only value A records but still Value B and C are present for this Pro value.

So I need a such query where it fetches only records that contains only A value.
Example: I need a such output where Pro value should only contain Value A only and if there are no such entries present then it should give 0 records.

Comment: Add some more sample data, different ID and pro value etc. And also specify the expected result. Take a look at [mcve] before you start.

Answer (score 1):

Use group by with having

Your select query gives only where both condition pro and value matches that would not mean that other values for pro negates/doesnt exist. Where in your select query just filters your select on whole table but you want to filter via each pro group not whole table likewise use below query to fetch values per each pro group having value as A

```
       SELECT ID, PRO, Max(Value) as 
      "Value"  , Max(Date) as "Date" from 
      table group by ID, PRO HAVING 
      Count(Distinct VALUE)=1 and 
       Max(Value)='A'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.pro = t.pro and t2.value <> 'A'
                 );
```

You can also use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when value <> 'A' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by pro) as num_notAs
      from t
     ) t
where num_notAs = 0;
```